# AWK set multiple delimiters for comma and quotes with commas

Tags: regex, linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV file where columns are comma separated and columns with textual data that have commas are quoted.

Sometimes, within quoted text there also exist quotes to mean things like inches resulting in more quotes.

Textual data without embedded commas do not have quotes.

For example:

```
A,B,C
1,"hello, how are you",hello
2,car,bike
3,13.3 inch tv,"tv 13.3"""
```

How do i use awk to print the number of columns for each row of which i should get

```
3
3
3
```

I thought of using `$awk -F'[,"]'`  but im getting way more columns than there is.

Help appreciated.

Comment: try field separator `awk --field-separator="," "{ print NF }"`

Comment: @authprivate never put an awk script in double quotes and `--field-separator=","` is exactly the same as `-F,`. To learn awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 9):

GNU awk has an extension to handle just such problematic CSV files.  Let's consider this first without quotes embedded within quotes:

```
$ awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{print NF}' file.csv
3
3
3
```

#### How it works

Instead of defining fields by a separator, `FPAT` allows us to define a field by a regular expression.  In this case, we define a field as either something that has no commas, `([^,]+)`, or as something that is surrounded by double quotes, `(\"[^\"]+\")`.

For more detail, see [the GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content).

### Handling quotes embedded within quotes

In the revised version of the question, we have the line:

```
3,13.3 inch tv,"tv 13.3"""
```

In this extended case, double quotes can be included within the double quoted field if they themselves are doubled.  To allow for this we extend the regex, as per lcd047's suggestion, to allow for an arbitrary number of such doubled-double-quotes within a field:

```
 awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\")"  '{print NF}' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @John1024. How can we also take into account if within the quotes, there were other quotes to for example specify inches? Please see my example above.

Comment: @jxn Change `FPAT` accordingly: `FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\")"`

Comment: @lcd047 Excellent suggestion.  I added it to the answer.

Comment: If you use single instead of double quotes around the FPAT definition then you don't need to escape all the double quotes within it: `-v FPAT='([^,]+)|("([^"]|"")+")'`. Also, if you want to allow for empty fields (try `abc,,def,"",ghi`) you should change the `+`s to `*`s: `-v FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")'`.

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the field contents, use @John1024's solution, otherwise this is all you need:

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/"[^"]+"/,""); print NF}' file
3
3
3
```